# Which event type should I use for common user actions with Firebase?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I started to integrate the current Firebase SDK into my Unity 2018 project and registered my project and App in the Firebase console. After some research, I realized that Firebase provides predefined events to track user actions within the app/game.

Because it's not a typical game, most of the events provided don't fit and I started to use `EventSelectContent` to track different user clicks, downloading and deleting content, trigger AR targets and so on.

```
public static void LogToFirebase(string key, string value)
{
    if (_firebaseInitialized)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{nameof(LogToFirebase)} {key} -> {value}");

        FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventSelectContent, key , value);
        //FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

But is this the right approach to do so? Or what would be to best way to search and filter user's behavior in the Firebase dashboard.

Another approach was to use user properties, but I don't know, if that's the way to go.

At the end, I just wanna track some simple different events per user clearly readable in the dashboard with a key-value pair with no need to predefine them in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Firebase's pre-defined events if they're not the right ones for your app.  These events are really just there as suggestions for users who start an app and can't think of what events they might want to track.

In general, I expect that most app developers will create custom events for 95% of the events they're logging with analytics. So if you want to log triggering an AR target, do something like this:

```
    FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("ar_target_triggered", "target_id" , my_target_id);
```